# View multi row in single row

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: master and details

master:

```
Id    MeterNo   readdate
------------------------ 
1     12345     1/1/2016
2     67891     1/1/2016
```

details:

```
MasterId  RDNG_CODE  RDNG_VALUE
-------------------------------
1          20         2910
1          21         2711
2          30         8888
2          31         9999
2          32         7777
```

The result:

```
MeterNo   RDNG_CODE_20  RDNG_CODE_21  RDNG_CODE_30 RDNG_CODE_31  RDNG_CODE_32
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345     2910          2711          NULL         NULL          NULL
67891     NULL          NULL          8888         9999          7777
```

Comment: search for PIVOT in SQLServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @tblMaster TABLE(Id INT,MeterNo INT,readdate DATE);
INSERT INTO @tblMaster VALUES
 (1,12345,'1/1/2016')
,(2,67891,'1/1/2016');

DECLARE @tblDetails TABLE(MasterId INT, RDNG_CODE INT,RDNG_VALUE INT);
INSERT INTO @tblDetails VALUES
 (1,20,2910)
,(1,21,2711)
,(2,30,8888)
,(2,31,9999)
,(2,32,7777);

SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT m.Id AS MasterID
          ,m.MeterNo
          ,'RDNG_CODE_' + CAST(d.RDNG_CODE AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
          ,d.RDNG_VALUE 
    FROM @tblMaster AS m
    INNER JOIN @tblDetails AS d ON m.Id=d.MasterId  
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(RDNG_VALUE) FOR ColumnName IN(RDNG_CODE_20,RDNG_CODE_21,RDNG_CODE_30,RDNG_CODE_31,RDNG_CODE_32)
)p
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for PIVOT statement

```
SELECT MasterId, 
[20] [RDNG_CODE_20], [21] [RDNG_CODE_21], [30] [RDNG_CODE_30], [31] [RDNG_CODE_31], [32] [RDNG_CODE_32]
FROM
(SELECT MasterId, RDNG_CODE, RDNG_VALUE
    FROM @Table) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(RDNG_VALUE)
FOR RDNG_CODE IN ([20], [21], [30], [31], [32])
) AS PivotTable;
```